# Retrieving system and os info

Tags: c++, osx-mavericks

In my c/c++ application, I want to show some system and os info like,

- Unique id which identifies the machine.
- OS name.
- OS architecture
- Manufacturer
- Model

On win, I am retrieving these info through WMI,

1. Class : Win32_ComputerSystemProduct, Key : UUID
2. Class : Win32_OperatingSystem, Key : Name
3. Class : Win32_OperatingSystem, key : OSArchitecture
4. Class : Win32_ComputerSystem, Key : Manufacture
5. Class : Win32_ComputerSystem, Key : Model

On mac (10.9.5), so far, I am only able to get the Hardware UUID using IOKit.

Also tried to get os name using kOSBuildVersionKey but it does not work for me.

```
io_registry_entry_t ioRegistryRoot = IORegistryEntryFromPath(kIOMasterPortDefault, "IOService:/");
CFStringRef verKeyCf = (CFStringRef) IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(ioRegistryRoot, CFSTR(kOSBuildVersionKey), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
IOObjectRelease(ioRegistryRoot);
```

How do I get other details? Please suggest!

Thanks,
R.

Comment: In the 1400+ pages that make up the C++ standard, there's nothing of that sort. As you've discovered, this is dependent entirely on the individual C++ implementation for the host operating system, and you will have to research, yourself, what kind of information is available for each host operating system you intend to use for your application.

Answer (score -1):

This is well standardized by POSIX (which I believe includes OSX). To obtain OS metadata there you should use [uname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/uname.html) system call. I have no idea of iOS.

Comment: Not really.  The Unique ID is the MAC address of the ethernet card and requires low-level OSX-specific calls.  Other stuff requires calls to `sysctlbyname()`.

Comment: uname gives the info like,
sysname = "Darwin",
nodename = "Rudreshs-Mac-mini.local",
release = "13.4.0",
version = "Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Wed Dec 17 19:05:52 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64", machine = "x86_64"

I need info what is shown in "About This Mac"
software : OS X 10.9.5

Comment: I need a function which gives the output like sw_vers command.